# Rails activerecord: query for record by a datetime field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to query for records in the `TimeSlot` table by the field start_date which has type `datetime`. Here's what I've tried so far that's failed:

```
TimeSlot.where(:start_date => DateTime.new(2010, 9, 1))

TimeSlot.where(:start_date => DateTime.new(2010, 9, 1).to_s)

TimeSlot.where(:start_date => "2010-09-08")

TimeSlot.where(:start_date => "2010-09-08 00:00:00")
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Records with Datetime that match today's date - Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943872/find-records-with-datetime-that-match-todays-date-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Your queries look good to me.

Are you sure that you have a matching row in the db?

To debug, look in your logs/development.log file.

Added:

Problem could be timezones. Your query is using your server's timezone. Your data could be stored in a different timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting it is a timezone thing as well.  Everything in the DB is automatically converted to UTC by rails.  Queries 1 and 4 should work if there isn't an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from rubyonrails.org

> Client.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",
>     {:start_date => params[:start_date], :end_date => params[:end_date]})

or

> Client.where("created_at IN (?)",
>     (params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date))

Here is what I have for query all the TimeSlot start at "2010-09-08", if your start_date is a date field.

```
TimeSlot.where("start_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?", "2010-09-08", "2010-09-08")
```

If you start_date is a datetime field.

```
TimeSlot.where("start_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?", "2010-09-08", "2010-09-09")
```

Because the datetime start at 00:00:00