# Find Records with Datetime that match today's date - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of deals and need to find records where the date matches today's date.

From the rails console, the date field I need to match looks like this. I've assigned a record to deal for testing.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > deal.start
=> Tue, 10 May 2011 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

If I try to find any records matching the start date with today like this I get nil

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Deal.find_by_start(Date.today)
=> nil
```

then I thought I could match by converting Date.today to a datetime.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Date.today.to_datetime
=> Tue, 10 May 2011 00:00:00 +0000 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Deal.find_by_start(Date.today.to_datetime)
=> nil
```

How can I get this to work? I'm using Rails 3.

Edit:
I thought about converting them both to a consistent format which will works but not when trying to using the find_by_start method

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > deal.start.strftime("%a, %e %B %Y") == Date.today.strftime("%a, %e %B %Y")
=> true 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Deal.find_by_start.strftime("%a, %e %B %Y") == Date.today.strftime("%a, %e %B %Y")
NoMethodError: undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Keep in mind a DateTime holds a date and a time, so you're looking for records that have a precise value, not just the same day.

You can do this one of two ways. You can either select the range of time from the beginning of the day to the end, or you can create a `date` column to help group your data better.

The range version looks like this:

```
@deals = Deal.where('start BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all
```

The other one requires creating a new `start_date` column in your table and populating it with the dates accordingly. You can index this date and have your queries run much faster, as range selections aren't always quick on large sets of data.

Comment: Thanks. This works great and I'll use this for the short term and look at refactoring my code for performance improvements. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is also a more succinct version using ranges.
@deals = Deal.where(start: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day.. DateTime.now.end_of_day)

Comment: I'm finding that `Deal.where(start: Time.zone.now.midnight)` also works.

Answer (score 74):

**Rails 5.1** has introduced `Date#all_day` helper, which returns a range object for a given date:

```
Deal.where(start: Date.today.all_day)
```

You can also use SQL `DATE()` function for your goal, e.g.:

```rb
@deals = Deal.where('DATE(start) = ?', Date.today)
```

Comment: And if you realize you've stayed up too late debugging and "today" is now actually "yesterday" (or any other given date), `Deal.where(start: Date.parse("YYYY-MM-DD").all_day)` will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 10):

For those still on Rails 4:

To augment not_a_patch's answer above, I would use:

```
Deal.where(start: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

because `Time.zone` will use UTC (which is how your date time field is stored) while `DateTime.now` will not.

```
> DateTime.now
=> Fri, 08 Sep 2017 11:28:21 -0400
> Time.zone.now
=> Fri, 08 Sep 2017 15:29:53 UTC +00:00
```