# Rails filter on date returning no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm trying to filter records that were assigned on particular day (today) using this query:

```
assignments = p.assignments.where("assigned_date = ?", Date.today)
```

Even though I know these records exist, I always get a blank result back.
I've also tried ...where(:assigned_date => Date.today) with no luck.

The database schema is:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: assignments
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  name                 :string(255)
#  rep                  :integer
#  set                  :integer
#  instructions         :text
#  created_at           :datetime        not null
#  updated_at           :datetime        not null
#  player_id            :integer
#  actual_percentage    :float
#  predicted_percentage :float
#  assigned_date        :date
#
```

And in the console, when I type

```
p.assignments.first.assigned_date == Date.today
```

it returns true.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime holds a date and a time, so you're looking for records that have a precise value, not just the same day.

```
assignments = p.assignments.where('assigned_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all
```

should return what's expected

P.S.
all credits to [Tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943872/find-records-with-datetime-that-match-todays-date-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Well, the solution here itself didn't work. But I used `'assigned_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date, @date + 1.day'` and that worked. I suppose that's because its a Date object and not datetime.